Error in glue_data(), is.environment(.envir) is not TRUE in gtsummary()
I have used gtsummary for some time and never encountered any problems. However, recently I am encountering an error no matter what type of plot I am trying to make.
For example:
# Loading packages
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)

# Create summary table
iris %>%
  tbl_summary()

Or any other code I try yields this error:
Error in dplyr::mutate():
ℹ In argument: stat = as.character(...).
Caused by error in glue_data():
! is.environment(.envir) is not TRUE
I have tried updating all packages, restarting R, downloading R and RStudio again but to no avail.
I would be grateful for any advice.

I had the same issue and upgraded to the last version using
pak::pkg_install("ddsjoberg/gtsummary", dependencies = TRUE)
Now it is ok
S

The issue came from a breaking change in the glue package. The updated gtsummary is being submitted to CRAN today, and once accepted, you can install once again from CRAN. https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/issues/2011

The updated version of gtsummary is now on CRAN that addresses this issue. There was a breaking change in the glue package that affected gtsummary.

Try reinstalling/updating glue, this worked for me:
install.packages("glue")

