bookdown and gtsummary: Why is chunk name added to table caption?
I have a .Rmd file like this:
---
output:
  bookdown::html_document2
  #html_document
---

```{r mychunkname}
library(gtsummary)
trial %>%
  select(age, grade, response) %>%
  tbl_summary() %>%
  modify_caption(caption = "MY CAPTION")

library(knitr)
trial %>%
  kable(caption = "MY CAPTION")
```

When I change the output format from html_document to bookdown::html_document2, the caption of the first table looks like this in the html file: (#tab:mychunkname)MY CAPTION.
Why does that (#tab:mychunkname) part appear, and how do I get rid of that?
For crosschecking I included that second table - which has the expected caption in both output formats.
This is new behaviour, possibly introduced in an update of one of the packages?
I am on bookdown version 0.41, gtsummary version 2.0.4, R version 4.4.0.

can you revert one of the packages to an older version to try to isolate the problem? I would try to use an older version of bookdown first and if that fixes the issue.

Try updating all you packages, that worked for me.

I do have the most recent versions of both packages bookdown and gtsummary, and have updated all my other packages as well. So I tried what Mike suggested instead. Reverting bookdown to 0.40 or 0.39 didn't help. Reverting gtsummary to older versions didn't work (probably because of this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79053129/error-in-glue-data-is-environment-envir-is-not-true-in-gtsummary). Strange this works for you; to me it seems something has changed with gtsummary (or maybe one of its dependencies) that causes that '(#tab:mychunkname)' part to appear, at least on my machine.

It should be noted that as I said, the problem comes with using an output format that allows numbering tables (bookdown::html_document2, instead of html_document without table numbering). So maybe the table caption produced by gtsummary is no longer correctly translated with numbered tables? As in the second table of my example, the output should be “Table 1: MY CAPTION” (but actually is “(#tab:mychunkname)MY CAPTION”). Instead of the table number as a prefix, for some reason nowadays I get some string containing the chunk name.
